# Why I obtain this error when I try to use log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am absolutly new in **log4j** and I have the following problem.

Into a class named **Mailer** I declared my log4j **Logger** object, in this way:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);
```

and then I have put a logging into the class constructor (to test if the logger works fine), in this way:

```
public Mailer() {
    super();
    logger.debug("LOGGER IN ACTION !!! INTO Mailer CONSTRUCTOR !!!");
    setTimeoper();
}
```

The problem is that when enter into the class construcor the logger seems don't works fine and don't print my message but instead it I obtain this logger error (into the console):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (utility.Mailer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Into my project I have a **config** package that contains the **log4j.properties** file that have a minimalistic content that say to show the **DEBUG** log4j statment into the console:

## define the console appender

log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

```
# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender
```

I think that it is correct but I never specify that log4j have to do it (I don't know how and what I have to do)

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue and correctly configure log4j?

Tnx

Comment: `log4j.properties` must be at the root of the classpath if no explicit location is set.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok and if I want to put it into the config package how can I specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log4j [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) states

> The exact default initialization algorithm is defined as follows:
>
> 1. Setting the log4j.defaultInitOverride system property to any other value then "false" will cause log4j to skip the default initialization
>      procedure (this procedure).
> 2. Set the resource string variable to the value of the log4j.configuration system property. The preferred way to specify the
>      default initialization file is through the log4j.configuration system
>      property. **In case the system property log4j.configuration is not
>      defined, then set the string variable resource to its default value
>      "log4j.properties"**.
> 3. Attempt to convert the resource variable to a URL.
> 4. If the resource variable cannot be converted to a URL, for example due to a MalformedURLException, then search for the resource from the
>      classpath by calling
>      org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.getResource(resource, Logger.class)
>      which returns a URL. Note that the string "log4j.properties"
>      constitutes a malformed URL.
> 5. If no URL could not be found, abort default initialization. **Otherwise, configure log4j from the URL.**

Since you haven't specified such a property, log4j will look for a `log4j.properties` at the root of the classpath. Your properties file is with `config` and so log4j can't find it. Either move it or provide a system property with its location.

Comment: If I put it in the root of classpath works fine but what can I do to use it in the case the log4j.properties file is into the config package?

Comment: @AndreaNobili See point 2 in the quote and my paragraph after it.

Comment: I read it but I don't know how exactly do it. Can you show me a code snippet?

Comment: @AndreaNobili There is no code snippet. Provide a system property when launching your Java process. `java -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/config MyMain`.